# Hide the contents for specific post

Tags: posts, plugin-development

I would like to hide the contents of a specific post from showing. `remove_post_type_support`does not seem to work.

```
add_action('template_redirect',array($this,'hide_post_contents'));
   public funcion hide_post_contents() 
{
   if(is_single(3))
    {
        remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'title' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.

Comment: It's really complicated here, you said you want to remove content from frontend then why you used remove_post_type_support() ?? first dig those functions purpose then try something that might sense to others

Answer (score 9):

Your code doesn't seem to be trying to hide the content, but you can use [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/) filter to return an empty content if you are on a specific post page. For example:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'hide_post_contents');

function hide_post_contents( $content ) {
   if( is_single(3) ) {
        return '';
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Also, there is a mistype in your code. `funcion` must be changed to `function`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the condition for page id where you are displaying the_content() function.

```
if( !is_single(101) ) {
    the_content()
}
```